# Hexadecimal conversion from a file

Tags: c

What is wrong with my code? I am trying to read in from a file line by line and convert the numbers in the form of 0x"hex numbers" into integers. It is returning just 1 line and then it ends, my input is something like this

0x9C40

0x3B9AC9FF

0x754893gf

0x754893gf

0x754893gf

0x754893gf

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


 #include <stdio.h>

 #define MAXCHAR 1000
 int main() {
     FILE *fp;
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    char* filename = "C:\\test.txt";
    int number;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
   if (fp == NULL){
      printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
      return 1;
     }
   while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL)
       number = (int)strtol(str, NULL, 0);
    printf("%d\n", number);
   fclose(fp);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What value does "g" represent?

Comment: What value do you want it to represent?

Comment: Maybe it should represent googol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to enclose the while block in curly braces:

```
while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL) {
    number = (int)strtol(str, NULL, 0);
    printf("%d\n", number);
}
```

Your code is equivalent to

```
while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL) {
    number = (int)strtol(str, NULL, 0);
}
printf("%d\n", number);
```

which explains why you get only one line of output.

Comment: Alright thank you, my mind is destroyed I have been programming this simple stuff for like 3 days and I can't even think anymore. How large of an int can this process produce? Say I take in a 64 bit hex can it cover that? IF not how?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: That depends. On many platforms, `int` is a 32-bit number, and `long long` is a 64-bit number, so `unsigned long long`, together with `strtoull` would be suitable.

Comment: What do you mean unsigned long long? Like specifically what do I need to change in my code?

Comment: @PaulthePirate, if you don't know about `unsigned` integer types, it is time to read a bit about integer types in C.

Comment: @JensGustedt I have been programming in a mad dash to get this done for about 4 days straight, I don't have time to read about that can't you just tell me the code to put into mine? I am going insane I can't even think I have to have this done now I don't have anymore more time left I have to have to do this now.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Declare the variable as `unsigned long long number;`, read it with `number = stroull(...)`, and print is with `printf(%llu\n", number);`. - But as I said, the actual size of `long long` depends on your platform, so you have to read the compiler documentation, or determine it with `sizeof(long long)`. - And what number should `0x754893gf` represent?? `g` is not a hexadecimal character.